# Where is Wine-3 icon in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

Currently running Ubuntu 17.10, and have just installed Wine-3.
Is there any way to invoke it other than using "winecfg" in a terminal session?

Comment: Since, WINE 1.6, WINE no longer produces menu entries. However, prefix managers, such as q4wine, do make entries. Also, desktop icons for programs installed in WINE should show in your menu. You can also manually create launchers.

Comment: Thanx, Ravary.  Will familiarize myself with Q4Wine. 
After a bit of thought, I might as well close this problem, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem (sorta) solved.**
I realized that Wine does not really need an app icon, as it is basically used only ONCE for each Windows app.
So, it is no big deal to invoke Wine using "**winecfg" from a terminal**, set up the Windows app, and it's done.
 Then the Windows app(s) will appear in the Ubuntu app list.
One just has to remember how to invoke WINE!